# Drupal7 hook field output

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I'm on a drupal7 project and need to hook the output of one normal textfield where I need to add a prefix to it.

// edit: this textfield is within a content type called Book. The field itself is called field_isbn which is just a normal single-line textfield. What I need is a prefix for the output of that field.

Is that possible?
Thank you

Comment: You're going to have to be a bit more specific...where is this textfield? Is it part of a custom form? A form provided by a core module? A node add/edit form?

Comment: your right... I edit my question. The field is within a content-type

Comment: You should be able to go to "admin/structure/types/manage/book/fields/field_isbn" and set the prefix for the field there...is this what you mean?

Comment: @Clive: yes that's what I meant, but the problem is: Prefix and Suffix are only avail on number-fields, not text-fields. :)

Comment: Ohhhh I get you :) I think you'll need to delve into code for this, I'll add an answer

Comment: @Lumio: You mean you need to add prefix to the textfield on the form, right? or is it the output/content of the field you are referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I didn't think of having a template for the field itself. So that would be the easiest solution:

http://drupal.org/node/1089656

The template-content can then be found in /modules/field/theme/field.tpl.php

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would probably be to write a small custom module that implements [`hook_field_widget_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_form_alter/7):

```
function MYMODULE_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {
  if ($context['field']['field_name'] == 'field_isbn') {
    $element['#field_prefix'] = 'ISBN'; // Or whatever
  }
}
```

This hook was only added in Drupal 7.8 so make sure you're core version is up to date and once you've cleared Drupal's cache you should be good to go.

Comment: hm... I try to implement this in my template so I call ewtheme_field_widget_form_alter - but the function does not get called when navigate to the page.

Comment: You can't do it in a theme I'm afraid it'll have to be a custom module...the hook is not invoked for themes, just modules :/

Comment: omg... I just found a more easy way :) there is a template-file for that... I didn't thought about having an extra template for the field itself